# OR in if condition raises "unexpected T_VARIABLE" error

Tags: php, syntax-error, conditional-statements

I'm stuck. I just want a simple OR inside an if condition and php always raises an error:

My Code:

```
if( ($value > 0.01 || $seconds < 100) ):
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
```

Comment: Post your complete if condition, please, are you closing it with `endif` and whether you are comparing are really numbers?

Comment: could you post some surrounding code?

Comment: php > if( ($value > 0.01 || $seconds < 100) ) : echo 'pwet';endif;
works normally so I guess you have done something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Unexpected [parser token](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) errors usually indicate you have a syntax or nesting error somewhere ***at or before*** the given line, so make sure you check your previous lines too. You might just be missing a semicolon or closing bracket somewhere.

Answer (score 12):

I've been struggling with the same problem, and now I finally decided to get to the bottom of it. Turns out the space character that I had after the || operator isn't actually space (= %20), it's %A0 (no idea how that happened). I'm using gEdit on Ubuntu, seems like Windows/Notepad treats them both as regular space.

So the lesson here is, check that your characters really are what you think they are.

Comment: This seems to be the problem for me to. Removed the space, and it works.

Comment: I was about to think that I know something wrong in PHP before reading your comment. Thank you.

Comment: Happened to me with VSCode today.

Answer (score 2):

change your code into this:

```
if(($value > 0.01)||($seconds < 100))
{

}
```

hope it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more code, The following code works at my computer:

```
<?php
$value = 2;
$seconds = 10;
if( ($value > 0.01 || $seconds < 100) ) {
  echo("OK");
} else {
  echo("fail");
}
?>
```